# How to return all the contacts which are all saved in DB?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have created a contact-saving app. I am not able to return all the contacts that are all saved in DB, the query did not return a unique result: 2

My Controller

```
public ModelAndView getAllContacts() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("getAllUser.jsp");
    User user = userda.getAllContacts();
    mav.addObject(user);
    return mav;
```

My JPA Repository

```
@Query(value ="SELECT * from USER", nativeQuery = true)
User getAllContacts();
```

Model class

```
@Entity(name = "USER")
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public String toString() {
        return "Person Name is " + " : " + name + " and " + " Mobile Number is " + " : " + id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow [ask] please

Comment: `User` is only a single object, it cannot hold multiple values

Answer (score 0):

Your repo assume only ONE entry `User getAllContacts();`.
You load all contacts, you need a list of user ... `List<User> getAllContacts()`

Hint: Your repo can also inherit from [CRUD Repo](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html). There you have some methods out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You have get list of Contacts e.g

```
public List<Contact> getAllContact(){
}
```

In My Case i get book entity

**Book.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String bookname;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Author author;
}
```

**BookDao.java**

```
public interface BookDao extends CrudRepository<Book, Integer> {
    public Book findById(int id);
}
```

**BookService.java**

```
@Component
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    //get all lists
    public List<Book> getAllBooks(){
        List<Book> list = (List<Book>) this.bookRepository.findAll();
        return list;
    }

    //get book by id
    public Book getBookById(int id){
        Book book = this.bookRepository.findById(id);
        return book;
    }
}
```

**BookController.java**

```
@RestController
// @RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    //get all books handler
    @GetMapping("/books")
    public List<Book> getBook(){
       List<Book> list =  this.bookService.getAllBooks();
    }
}
```